# Using AngularJS with npm

Tags: angularjs, npm

Any idea how I can autoload, concatenate and minify resources from node_modules when using npm as a package manager for a client side app created with angular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes.
simply install [angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular) using `npm install angular --save`

then for minifing etc' you could use [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) or [similar solutions](https://webpack.github.io/docs/comparison.html)